# Retrofit in android Activity lifecycle to keep data fresh

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

My retrofit interface method is returning rx `Single` with the response

```
@GET("/data")
Single<Response<List<Foo>>> getData();
```

and in my Activity `onStart()` method i call `getData()` to populate the data and until that am showing a loading `Progress` it will dismiss on success or fail

```
   getData().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> showProgress("loading"))
            .doOnSuccess(listResponse -> hideProgress())
            .subscribe(new SingleSubscriber<Response<List<Foo>>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Response<List<Cat>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) setItems(response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    hideProgress(error.getMessage());
                }
            })
```

the first time i start the `Activity` all goes well the `Progress` will show and on success or fail it dissmised

**The problem is**
whenever i start a new `Activity` via `startActivity()` and then back to my `Activity` `onStart()` is called again and my `Retrofit` call gets executed again (*i did that to keep my **data fresh** every time i enter my `Activity`*)

 but what happens is the `Progress` is shown till ever, no Success, no Fail happen, i even logged the request i am making on the server and there is no request being requested "at my second time not the first time the `Activity` opened" 
what could the problem be is it in the `Retrofit` or `Rxjava`

is there any approaches to do the **fresh data** thing every time the activity is started or poped from the stack

Are we till ever doomed with the `Android activity lifecycle` curse...

Comment: I would suggest you to try `OkHttpClient`, and log the request and the response on the device. It will show you in detail what and when happens with your network request.

Comment: @arcticwhite thanks i thought about it i'll try ,it but i need more than my question are there any other approaches/best-practices to keep data synced in retrofit

Comment: This is not the problem with Retrofit2, it's just a simple logic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sixth sense told me that it is a silly mistake or a misunderstand 
i was using a `CompositeSubscription` to add all my calls to it and unsubscribe all of them safely in `onStop()` by calling `CompositeSubscription.unsubscribe()` to prevent resource leaks
what was happening is when i return to my activity i was adding the same `subscription` to the composite and it was unsubscribed immediately

the docs says :

> public void unsubscribe()
>
> Unsubscribes itself and all inner subscriptions.
>
> After call of this method, new Subscriptions added to CompositeSubscription >will be unsubscribed immediately.

and i resolve the problem by calling `clear()` instead

> public void clear()
>
> Unsubscribes any subscriptions that are currently part of this >CompositeSubscription and remove them from the CompositeSubscription so that >the CompositeSubscription is empty and able to manage new subscriptions.

then you are able to add the same subscription again and being called as it normally behave

24 hours lost for that. -_- .

Answer (score 0):

You are not stopping your activity when you return to your activity you need to override your `onResume()` method. Instead of `onCreate()` or `onStart()` call your getData method in `onResume()`. This will do the job.

Comment: when you start activity via `startActivity()` your activity is stopped and when it pops from the stack it get started

Comment: when activity pops from stack it resumes so call your getData method in onResume(). You dont need to override onStart() just in your on create method create static retrofit instance and then in your onResume() call your getData method. Try this it will do the job. If you need further assistance feel free to contact me. Happy coding bro :)

Comment: thanks bro but what happens when starting a new activity is `onPause() -> onStop()` and when pop it from the stack `onStart() -> onResume()` you got me doubting about what i know i logged the method to recheck 
thank you alot i did as the guy up says i intercepts the calls of retrofit 
the `Single` get subscribed the second time but the call is not being called ,i am sure that the problem will be silly one but those problem how got you running after alll day